# Complete JSON-pointer implementation

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a Javascript implementation out there of the complete JSON-pointer specification as in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901?

I found a few ([json-pointer](https://github.com/manuelstofer/json-pointer), [node-jsonpointer](https://github.com/janl/node-jsonpointer), [jsonpointer.js](https://github.com/alexeykuzmin/jsonpointer.js)), but none seem to handle, for example, the special "-" token.

Does anyone have experience using JSON pointer? Which implementation is the most mature?

Comment: I realise this question is pretty old, but what do you expect support for "-" to look like? RFC6901 states: "Note that the use of the "-" character to index an array will always
   result in such an error condition because by definition it refers to
   a nonexistent array element.  Thus, applications of JSON Pointer need
   to specify how that character is to be handled, if it is to be
   useful." This suggests that dash is only useful for setting values, not retriving them.

Comment: https://github.com/janl/node-jsonpointer supports using dash to set it would seem.

Comment: JSON Machine makes use of "-" for iteration: https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine